# celery: hard time limit defaults to 300 no matter what

Tags: python, celery

I am using the documented method of using the @task decorator for my task but it completely ignores this and times out at 300 seconds.

```
@task(time_limit=333333)
def process:
```

as you can see hard limit reached at 300s.

```
[2015-02-25 02:12:03,205: ERROR/MainProcess] Task celery.local.process[982190a3-6c47-4e6d-8695-1c065cd05723] raised unexpected: TimeLimitExceeded(300,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 640, in on_hard_timeout
    raise TimeLimitExceeded(job._timeout)
TimeLimitExceeded: TimeLimitExceeded(300,)
[2015-02-25 02:12:03,205: ERROR/MainProcess] Hard time limit (300s) exceeded for celery.local.process[982190a3-6c47-4e6d-8695-1c065cd05723]
[2015-02-25 02:12:08,404: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-1' pid:13888 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
```

I would like to set the hard limit to a large value and not have it revert back to 300 mysteriously.

Comment: Your code seems sound have you restarted the worker?

Comment: yes I have restarted it

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to set `soft_time_limit` as well:

```
@task(time_limit=333333, soft_time_limit=333333)
def process:
```

The soft time limit will trigger an Exception which you can catch, the latter kills the job.